# Is it a good idea to do MS two times in separate disciplines than a PhD for an industry job?

Tags: masters, application, industry

I am getting admitted to a school(college as it is called in many parts of the world) that provides 5 years integrated BS-MS dual degree in the natural sciences (Physics, Chemistry, Maths, Bio). You can major in anyone and minor in some other discipline in this school.

However, I am very interested in taking up CS (which is neither offered as a major neither a minor here) and going for an industry job for eg. as a data analyst or machine learning scientist in some IT firm.

Note: I am **not** interested in a Ph.D. or making a career in academia.

So, is it advisable to go for another MS in CS from some separate school after doing the integrated degree from here? Do universities in US/UK accept students for an MS if he already has an MS in a separate discipline? Will it help me in an industry job?

I also have a second option. Dropping my first year and getting admitted to a separate school which offers a CS degree next year. Is year loss advisable? (Advisable in the sense will it have any detrimental effect in my future career?)

Answer (score 1):

Don't make some elaborate plan of doing this entry degree and then another one.  You could even consider to drop out of this school and go to another that has CS. Or just go to work, in whatever IT position you can find.

If you feel like you must stay in the school you are at, my advice is to do whatever subjects appeal to you and just try to pick up some computer skills as available from whatever courses, projects you can.  Or even just on the side for fun or for small pay.

P.s.  Pick up as much statistics as you can.  That stuff never goes out of style and is incredibly relevant to computer algorithm optimization (as well as all kinds of other practical things)

P.s.s.  You are young and should somewhat be open to different careers.  Machine learning is a bit of a fad.